# Compilation of QT on win fails

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted to compile QT for use with MSVC2013, and followed the [instructions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-building.html). However, nmake fails with

```
error RC2135: file not found: hierarchy.ico
```

while compiling the example `hierarchy` from `activeqt`. Did I miss something while configuring? Or should I rather simply exclude the examples from the build?

EDIT: Another alternative would be to exclude `activeqt`, because I don't need the functionality. But nevertheless I am interested in my mistake...

Comment: It's not unusual to have broken examples on untested stuff. But qtactiveqt is actually build by CI: http://testresults.qt-project.org/ci/QtActiveQt_5.4_Integration/latest-success/win64-msvc2013_developer-build_qtnamespace_Windows_81/log.txt.gz and it's fine.

Comment: I were using QT 5.3.2 (-everywhere-*.zip), not the git data. Therefore I think that it should be tested.